# Spark application with Jackson version 2.8 is incompatible with Apache Spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark application which uses Jackson 2.8 API and I use spark 1.6 as provided (scope) dependency in application pom.xml. When I try to deploy the Spark application in cluster mode, the Jackson older version from Spark 1.6 build is been picked causing the application to fail.

I tired supplying 2.8 Jackson jar through "--jars" option, build Uber application jar with latest Jackson dependency included and userClasspathFirst option on executor/driver - None of these options helped.

I placed the latest Jackson jar in all Spark worker nodes in the same location and added the path to the executor classpath option - Only in this option, the latest Jackson version is picked. In this solution every time I add a new worker node to my application, I have to place the latest Jackson which I find as a disadvantage. If someone has a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to shade Jackson. For example in maven you would do something like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.fastxml.jackson</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>com.mycompany.shaded.com.fastxml.jackson</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <finalName>FatJarName</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The idea is that it will basically rename the jackson package and will change your internal access to use it. Then submit the new fat jar.

Note: This does not always work (specifically if you use reflection to access jackson it can point to the wrong version).

Comment: Thanks Assaf! It works for me. Are there any disadvantages/issues when using relocation feature in Shade plugin?

Comment: Posted a different question to understand the downsides of relocation feature, as I feel it is out of this topic.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710931/downsides-of-using-shade-plugin-relocation-feature

Comment: @PrabuSoundarRajan The most important one that I know is that if you use reflection it can break (this happened to me with Spring for example). Similar issues can occur if you have a manifest which relies on the package name. In addition, this means there are essentially two different copies of the package (including for example two instances of static elements) which can cause issues. It just means you have to be careful